# Removing an Android library

Tags: android, libs

I am using a library in my Android project. But I need to replace it by a new one. So I removed it and added the new one to the libs/ folder.

But Eclipse keeps saying :

```
Project is missing required library:'libs/old-lib.jar'
```

How can I do this properly ?

thanks for helping

Comment: @KaiserM11 He's using Eclipse. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, make sure the jar is not in the list, otherwise remote it.

Then click the Order & Export tab, and ensure the jar is unchecked.

Comment: Thank you ! the library was removed :)